# Secure erase verification methods for different storage media?

Tags: smart, secure-erase, hdparm, smartctl, data-sanitization

Do secure erase technologies available on different types of media set a status or verification flag?

Is there a industry standard to verify when a drive has gone through the process?

Comment: No, to these questions AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

**First question**: YES and NO

1. Depending on the specifications of your device (whether it has an SSD or HDD), you may have access to different erase methods (or sanitization methods). These methods can include **write verification**, multiple passes, and even the application of specific patterns (such as all 00s) during the final pass. An example of a sanitization method is DoD 5220.22-M and its variants. For more information on some of these sanitization methods, you can refer to: https://www.lifewire.com/data-sanitization-methods-2626133.
2. Using a method that appends a distinctive pattern (such as 00 or any other chosen pattern) during the final pass is highly advantageous when desiring additional "manual" confirmation of the successful completion of secure erase (SE) process. This could be easy done via command line ( assuming a Linux shell and a SATA disk):
   `dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | tr -d '\0' | read -r -d '' && echo "Disk contains non-zero data" || echo "Disk only contains zeros"`

**Second question**: MORE or LESS (ahah sorry for that^^)

3. No "industry standards", but rather a NIST "guideline" (which could potentially become a standard if mandated by your specific industry). Please refer to the NIST publication at this link: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-88r1.pdf
4. On page 20 (of NIST SP 800-88r1 document),you will find the guideline concerning the "verification of sanitization results" which explains the principles and requirements of erasure verification. This requirement can be easily satisfied by utilizing a known simple pattern for verification (refer to point 2).

However, it is worth noting the presence of CE (cryptographic erasure), another erasure technique that proves highly effective for modern SSDs featuring internal encryption mechanisms. However, it is important to consider the pros and cons of CE, as its suitability may not be readily apparent in certain cases (e.g critical industries and cybersecurity concerns), as extensively explained in the NIST SP 800-88r1 guidelines.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You don't want to be wiping SSDs by writing a lot of data to them. If they're encrypted, all that's needed is to remove the encryption keys. The DoD methods apply to HDDs.

Comment: hi Tetsujin. I understand your point, but your comment is wrong and off topic (i'm saying it friendly). The question was EXPLICITELY related to the "secure erase" functionality. Moreover, a lot of SSD secure erase functionalities do actually implements DoD methods (in SSD).

Comment: Your first link is entirely about HDDs. your second link won't open. Aside from the pointless waste of write cycles, a regular 'overwrite' strategy won't touch the overprovisioning on an SSD. Really, all you need to do is wipe the encryption keys & the data is gone forever.

Comment: I shared the first link because it gives good details about sanitization methods and their principles. Second link is working in my side...weird (in all case it is easy to google for the NIST SP-800-88r1. The concept you are talking about is the CE (cryptographic Erase), and is not the subject of this question here. CE and SE are available on both SSD and HDD (depending of specs), because it is devices firmware callable ATA functions (when implemented). Moreover, if you read the NIST spec (again), you would see that choosing between CE and SE method is not as obvious as you believe.

Comment: There are pro and cons using CE methods. Moreover, BoB R seems to be interested by the industrial "constraints" involving risks scenarios slightly different than a student in his garage. Thus, making the CE method not 100% safe and even less safer than SE (yes yes, it is explicitely written in the NIST document). In an other side i agree with you that SE may have much more impact on SSD life and health.

Comment: The reason I ask about 'secure erase' assuming non-random fill is that it seems to lend itself to a verification on any medium magnetic or flash; more than 'data sanitization' ie. dropping encryption keys or generating new ones as done for example on macOS with filevault.

Comment: Okay i see. As written in my answer, the SE (secure erase) is usually configurable by selecting a a specific erasure algorithm, where some of them makes verification that data is actually written or not (cf. Point 1). So you don't just SE, you do SE with a specific sanitization algorithm (like DoD, or anything else specifying the number of "passes" and patterns of data written, etc..). The defaut algorithm used when you run SE is probably specified in the drive datasheet, and the way to select the one you prefer having writes verification or not. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Not sure what's you stand here but I think what @Tetsujin was thinking is that you are implying we can have *effective* "SE" by "implementing" it ourselves, i.e. sending normal writing commands to LBAs, but the truth is when these days LBAs are not statically mapped to the same memory (and perhaps not even same HDD sectors), and also the potential optimization/compression for pattern writing, "SE" might be fully performed when you instruct the firmware to do it, which *hopefully* would cause it to reach all the memory/sectors behind, and one can confirm only if he can examine them *directly*

Comment: Therefore, when it comes to verification, we cannot really determine whether it is "really" "SE" by just checking if all the LBAs have the same pattern. It could be a result of many things, and one of them being merely all LBAs are unmapped (in particular, but not necessarily, if they are zero or one filled).

Comment: Another obvious might worth stating is that, since the firmware is basically a "black box", you can at best guess what it is doing behind the scene. Vendors can (and often do) implement SE/CE-related command/feature sets any way they like (at least until they get sued or class actions, if possible), let alone the command/feature sets are quite vaguely defined in the various specs anyway. (It got better in what I call the "sanitize era", but still.) One reason is that many laymen would consider / think that it is secure as long as they see all the LBAs read zero.

Answer (score 0):

NVMe base spec does define a field in the Sanitize Status Log which indicates whether the drive has ever been *sanitized*. Look for `SSTAT` in the spec file which is publicly available.

With that said, the Sanitize command is just one of the commands defined in the spec that can be used to wipe a drive. Another example would be the Format NVM command, in which a Secure Erase Settings (`SES`) field is defined for the user to request a desired Secure Erase operation. The `SSTAT` field is most likely not changed if the drive was wiped with this command instead, regardless of the value set in the `SES` field. (Btw, I am not so sure in most consumer grade drive, value of the `SES` field actually makes a difference behind the scene.)

The Sanitize feaure set introduced in more recent ATA/ACS spec also seem to have a field in its command output to indicate whether a sanitize operation has been completed *without error* (i.e., it is not clearly defined whether a new drive should have the bit set).